# How to do a Kernel Density map from weighted point observations using a Cauchy kernel?

Tags: r, kernel-density

I need to produce a kernel density map, but instead of using a common kernel function such as Gaussian, I need to use the Cauchy kernel function.

I have tried the Kernel Density tool in ArcGIS and Heatmap plugin in QGIS, but neither of them have the option to use the Cauchy kernel function.

I am new in GIS and R, and I don’t know how to proceed.

Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: Welcome.  Please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question to include what GIS software you are using, what you have tried/what hasn't worked for you.

Comment: Could you explain why you need a Cauchy kernel?